# php inserting multiple session variables into mysql through my query

Tags: php, sql, session, insert

I'm trying to insert the values my session is currently holding into my mysql table.

```
$insert_sql = 'INSERT INTO booked_rooms (date_start, date_end, adults, children, fk_room_id, title, first_name, last_name, address, city, state_province, zip_postal, telephone, email) 
VALUES ('.$_SESSION['date_start'].$_SESSION['date_end'].$_SESSION['adults'].$_SESSION['children'].$_SESSION['room_id'];', $title , $first_name , $last_name , $address , $city , $state , $zip , $telephone , $email)';

$insert = mysqli_query($con, $insert_sql) or die ($mysqli_error());
```

It should work, but I'm not sure how to use the $_session variables in this context

Comment: comma separated and add quotes.? `$mysqli_error` what is it?

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in your query. try like this

```
$insert_sql = 'INSERT INTO booked_rooms (date_start, date_end, adults, children, fk_room_id, title, first_name, last_name, address, city, state_province, zip_postal, telephone, email) 
VALUES ("'.$_SESSION['date_start'].'","'.$_SESSION['date_end'].'","'.$_SESSION['adults'].'","'.$_SESSION['children'].'","'.$_SESSION['room_id'].'", "$title" ," $first_name" , "$last_name" , "$address" , "$city" , "$state" , "$zip" , "$telephone" , "$email")';
```

Comment: it will not work, because of string values and without quotes

Answer (score 0):

**Issues in your query:**

- You need to split your `SESSION` values in commas.
- Use quotes for string values.
- Don't know what is it? `$mysqli_error()` you need to remove `$` sign.

**Modified Query:**

```
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO booked_rooms (date_start, date_end, adults, children, fk_room_id, title, first_name, last_name, address, city, state_province, zip_postal, telephone, email) 
VALUES ('".$_SESSION['date_start']."','".$_SESSION['date_end']."','".$_SESSION['adults']."','".$_SESSION['children']."','".$_SESSION['room_id']."', '$title' ,'$first_name' , '$last_name' , '$address' , '$city' , '$state' , '$zip' , '$telephone' , '$email')";
```